# Flutter app not working in android 12. Gives me Error INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

Flutter app is not working in Android 12. I have tried various things like adding `exported="true"` but still i am not able to run the app on Android 12.

Error:

```js
adb: failed to install D: \Flutter BLE May 2022\ SW_Mobile_Platform\ build\ app\ outputs\ flutter - apk\ app.apk: Failure[INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app / vmdl1121899374.tmp / base.apk(at Binary XML file line #184): org.altbeacon.beacon.startup.StartupBroadcastReceiver: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for
android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]
```

Here is my `Manifest` file:

```js
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ble_app_flutter">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth.le"
        android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="ble_app_flutter"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".BLEActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to AndroidManifest file (your_project_folder->android->app->src->main->AndroidManifest.xml):

Just add `android:exported="true"` inside your activity tag. Check the following:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:exported="true" //Just add this to your manifest
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Didn't you read my post? I have mentioned that i have already added `android:exported="true"` but still its not working.